# Elastic Search - Get the matching field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using ElasticSearch to implement search on a Webapp (Rails + Tire). When querying the ES server, is there a way to know what field of the Json returned matched the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [*highlight*](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/highlighting/) feature, see support in Tire: https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/highlight_test.rb.

Do not use the Explain API for other then debugging purposes, as this will negatively affect the performance.

Comment: Thanks, you're doing a great job with that gem!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [Explain API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/explain/) from elastic search? The output of explain gives you a detailed explanation of why a document was matched, and it's relevance score.

The algorithm(s) used for searching the records are often much more complex than a single string match. Also, given the fact that you have the possibility of a term matching multiple fields (with possibly different weights), it may not be easy to come up with a simple answer. But, looking at the output of Explain API, you should be able to construct a meaningful message.

Comment: Thanks, while I can get that from an explain call, it looks too costly for that routine.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I wasn't sure if you planned to have this permanently. I was under the impression this was a debugging scenario. I think `highlight` would be a better approach as @Karmi points out.